# PHP : How to replace = only without replacing <= and >=

Tags: php, string, replace

I need to replace `=` in string with the `==` sign.

The issue is that I don't want to replace `<=` and `>=` signs.

Thank you

Comment: Can we assume there are whitespaces around the `=`, or just not `<=` and `>=`? It'd be helpful if you posted your code attempt as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with this regex, which looks for `=` signs which are not preceded by `<`, `>`, `!` or `=` or followed by `=`:

```
(?<![<>=!])=(?!=)
```

For example:

```
$string = "I need to replace = in string with == sign, but not in <=, != and >= signs.";
echo preg_replace('/(?<![<>=!])=(?!=)/', '==', $string);
```

Output:

```
I need to replace == in string with == sign, but not in <=, != and >= signs.
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/IpNN4)